# Ubuntu file permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I'm having some trouble with file permissions on an Ubuntu server. I'm using WinSCP to move files to the server. The server will work fine, and then after a while it appears that I no longer have permission to delete a file.

I'm connecting to the server using an account called **svadmin**, and the root directory of the Apache server is **/var/www**. Each website has it's own directory under this - i.e.

```
/var/www/site1
/var/www/site2
```

This is the output from the ls command...

```
cd /var/www
ls -al
drwxr-sr-x   4  svadmin  svadmin  4096 2009-06-12 14:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  15  root     root     4096 2009-05-05 15:47 ..
drwxr-sr-x   4  svadmin  svadmin  4096 2009-06-12 15:15  site1
drwxr-sr-x   4  svadmin  svadmin  4096 2009-06-12 15:15  site2
```

My understanding is that this mean the directory owner has read/write/execute? When I connect to the server using the svadmin account, shouldn't I be able to overwrite or delete files in /var/www/site1 or /var/www/site2?

I'm not very familiar with linux file/directory permissions, so have been struggling to work out what I should be doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**More info: (thanks for the quick replies!)**

Output of ls -al for /var/www/site1

```
drwxr-sr-x 4 svadmin svadmin 4096 2009-06-12 15:15 .
drwxr-sr-x 4 svadmin svadmin 4096 2009-06-12 14:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 svadmin svadmin 157  2009-05-12 13:23 error.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 svadmin svadmin 158  2009-05-12 13:23 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 svadmin svadmin 142  2009-05-12 13:23 index.php
drwxr-sr-x 2 svadmin svadmin 4096 2009-05-12 18:40 libraries
```

Error message When I try and delete the file:

```
rm admin.php
rm: cannot remove 'admin.php' : Read-only file system
```

**Even more info**
Just to add some possibly relevant information... everything was working until yesterday afternoon. At that point a coworker took out the SAN that the virtual machine file was on, and the web server had a less than graceful shutdown.

Comment: Can you post the output of ls -lA /var/www/site1/?

Comment: Could you also post any error you get when trying to delete a file?

Comment: I presume the above error is from winscp? Can you try to remove the files with rm (like, over ssh), and see if that generates an error.

Comment: I changed the error to what it is if I used rm - thanks again!

Comment: Check 'dmesg'; it may say while the filesystem is read-only. The message will hopefully be near the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a permissions problem.  The two clues are:

- rm: cannot remove 'admin.php' : Read-only file system
- everything was working until yesterday afternoon. At that point a coworker took out the SAN that the virtual machine file was on, and the web server had a less than graceful shutdown.

Somehow the filesystem containing /var/www dropped to "read only" probably when the SAN went away.  The output of the `mount` command should identify this filesystem with a (ro) flag at the end.

The fix is to figure out why it happened, make sure it's corrected, and remount the filesystem rw with this command:

`mount -oremount,rw $filesystem`

Comment: It sounds like /var/www is remotely mounted (on the aforementioned SAN), in which case, the debugging may need to happen on the fileserver.  That would mean that the server in question shows the filesystem mounted read/write, but the fileserver has the filesystem read-only.

Comment: Thanks - the problem was related to the SAN issue, and mounting the drive seemed to solve the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.

Comment: Or is fixed, rather.

Answer (score 0):

If you have rwx on a directory, that means you can edit the directory file, which amounts to removing and adding files.  Editing files is a function of their individual permissions.  What does an ls -l of one of the subdirectories look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the sticky bit.  Notice that the perms there aren't `drwxr-xr-x`, they are `drwxr-sr-x`.  Wikipedia says:

> The most common use of the sticky bit today is on directories, where, when set, items inside the directory can be renamed or deleted only by the item's owner, the directory's owner, or the superuser; without the sticky bit set, any user with write and execute permissions for the directory can rename or delete contained files, regardless of owner. Typically this is set on the /tmp directory to prevent ordinary users from deleting or moving other users' files. This feature was introduced in 4.3BSD in 1986 and today it is found in most modern Unix systems.

So, files are only writable and deletable by the group that put them there in the first place.

Comment: The "sticky" bit is not set, rather it's the "setgid" bit.  The setgid bit forces files dropped into the directory to be owned by the same group as the directory.  The sticky bit is indicated by a 't' in the last position of the perms, like so:

<pre>
$ mkdir test
$ chmod a+t test
$ ls -ld test
drwxr-xr-t 2 insyte staff 6 2009-07-16 16:52 test
</pre>